# Entity data framework in MVC - recurrent error database-first model update

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

This is probably the single biggest time-waster I have: I must have wasted cumulative days trying to get round it.

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and ASP.NET MVC 5, but don't think this is important - I've had this problem in other versions.  I accept that it's based on my ignorance.

I've got a reasonably complicated SQL Server database, and am using database-first model generation.  To keep things manageable, I've got about 20 different models, each containing tables on a particular theme.

So let's say I want to generate a model to contain tables to do with the maps in my database.  First thing to do is to add a new entity model database:

[image]

I want to call my model **webMap**:

[image]

I choose to generate the model from my database:

[image]

I've got a perfectly good connection string to the database in my web.config file, so I use that and choose not to save this:

[image]

I then choose the tables for which I want to generate classes, and these options:

[image]

What happens then is that it doesn't recognise the new database context:

[image]

The reason is (I think) in this file:

[image]

This has created a class named after a connection string:

[image]

If I change the partial class and constructor name like this:

[image]

then it solves the problem - until I next need to update the database.

Please forgive my ignorance about what's going on.  Although I like what entity frameworks do, I find the opacity of what's going on hard to work with.  Could any kind person tell me what I'm doing wrong, without delving into T4 transformations?  I've tried cleaning my solution and running custom tools, by the way.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Open the `edmx` file in the designer and click somewhere inside to select the conceptual model in the Properties window. Now look at `Entity Container Name` property. The value should be `Entities` - I think derived from your connection string name and no way to be specified during the Add wizard steps.

Simply change it to the desired name of the context (like `webMap`), save/build and you are done.

But make sure the `Namespace` and `Entity Container Name` property values are different.

Comment: I tried this, but it says that this name is already in use.  "EntityContainer name 'webMap' is already in use by another Entity Data Model in the project."

Comment: Well, then check the other `edmx` files to find which one is using that name. Or use different name. It works for me when I specify non existing name.

Comment: And make sure `Namespace` and `Entity Container Name` values are different.

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to **Ivan** and **garret** for their answers.  I've collated the information and put here a procedure which worked for me.  I don't claim to understand fully what's going on (but surely the point of a framework like this is that I shouldn't need to?).

Here's how I managed to create my model.  There are 6 steps.  I don't know which of them can be omitted, but following them all solved my problem.

**Step 1 - Delete any existing models referencing tblMap**

I found that I had inadvertently created another model.  Doing a global search for (in my case) **webMap** can help find if you are in the same position.

**Step 2 - clear the web.config file connection strings**

I don't understand why, but it appears that the connection strings in your web.config file show up as conflicting names in code.  So I did a search for **webMap** in my web.config file and deleted all connection strings containing it.  I think this is the step that I had previously omitted.

**Step 3 - Clean and rebuild the solution**

I cleaned the solution (no idea if this was necessary), then rebuilt it to ensure that the only errors I had left were in my code referencing the **webMap** database context which no longer existed.

**Step 4 - Follow the steps to add an ADO entity model**

But ... call the item name in the first screen something like **webMapModel**, the connection string something like **webMapEntities** (and choose to save this in the web.config file) and the namespace something like **webMapNamespace**.  Note that none of these is the **webMap** name I want to end up with.

**Step 5 - Change the entity container name**

Double-click on the model **.edmx** file which has been created to open it (this might not be necessary - it may be open already).  Click on the white background of the model to deselect any entities.  Press F4 to bring up properties.

[image]

Change the entity container name to **webMap** as shown above.

**Step 6 - Rebuild your solution**

At this point all my errors disappeared!

Answer (score 0):

Name of Your context, should be different than namespace.

Try to use this configuration:

[image: dbFirst]

And in next screen:
[image: dbFirstNext here]

And yes, it will add next connection string to web.config, but it's ok.

Comment: That's what I've been doing previously, but I thought I must have been doing something wrong because I've got about 20 different connection strings in my web.config file!

Comment: Just delete unused connection strings. You don't have 20 entity data models, right?
You need only one entity data model for one db, so you need only one connection string.